# Domain showing not secure but it has https and certificate installed

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have an issue with my domain.

I have installed an EV SSL Certificate successfuly, on ssl checker tools it shows me that the certificates is installed and everything is ok. The problem is that in front end I have **Not Secure**, however I can access with https:

I think that the problem is with Apache configuration. At the beginning I had php page and showed to me site is secure, after changing the php page for the website itself, it shows **Not Secure**

Here is my virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName subdomain.domain.org/
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domainFolder
  SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/file.key
SSLCertificateChainFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/file2.crt

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1

<Directory /var/www/html/domain>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME=~/.composer
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Please help

Comment: Use an online SSL testing tool.

Comment: I have used many and they showed me that my site has installed a valid certificate, the IP that resolves and the expiration date. But the problem is from Apache config

Comment: What is the actual domain name, then?

Comment: I must be missing something, but I did not understand what tells you that domething is not secure…

Comment: Never mind guys, I found the error, it was an image that had http: instead of https:, I was using it for the css of the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, browsers will complain when your HTTPS website has assets that are called using plain HTTP to the same domain because of the mixed content problem, and the reason is pretty simple: if your website is using an available HTTPS connection, why would anybody be using a plain HTTP one?

So, some good practice is calling your assets (JavaScript, images, CSS and so on), using helpers (if you're using some sort of framework) or referring them using as-is protocol URIs, like `//domain.of.website/js.file.js`.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
It was an image that was being called with http: instead of https: in my website styles.